# Armv7 Assembly - Extra console prompt "pi@raspberrypi:~ $ " when I press enter?

Tags: linux, assembly, arm, tty

I get this output from my program which takes a user input, and replaces the linefeed with a null terminating and prints it back out to the console

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./tester

Please enter 4 different numbers between 1-5 together without space or special characters. 
 
1234
1234
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

But when I type 123 I only get a single line prompt which is what I'm looking for when I enter 1234.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./tester

Please enter 4 different numbers between 1-5 together without space or special characters. 
 
123
123
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

This is the code I'm executing, it's as minimum as I could get it for minimum functional requirements.

```
 .global _start

_start:
 
  LDR r1, =prompt
        BL _sPrint
    
        LDR     r1, =userInput      @ point to the space allocated for input
        MOV     r2, #4              @ set the limit of character to read in
        BL _sInput
        
        LDR r1, =userInput
        BL _sPrint
        
        Ldr r1, =newline
        BL _sPrint
        
        B _exit
    
    
    @_sPrint prints out a string based on it's variable length determined by _strlen
    @strlen, and findEnd are both needed for _sPrint.
    
    _sPrint:
        MOV r7, #4          @sets r7 to console STDOUT
        MOV r0, #1          @set WRITE destination to STDOUT (terminal)
        PUSH {r0, r1, lr}   
        BL _strLen          @gets the stringlength and the end
        POP {r0, r1, lr}    
        SWI 0
        mov pc, lr
    
    _strLen:
      mov   r2, #0
                    @find end of strlen finds the end of the string and stores the length in r2 for console output
    findEnd:
      LDRB  r0, [r1], #1
      ADD   r2, r2, #1
      CMP   r0, #0
      BNE findEnd
      SUB   r2, r2, #1
      MOV   pc, lr
    
    _sInput:
        PUSH {R1-R8, lr}
        MOV r7, #3          @register r7 being set to 3 to indicate message being read in (read syscall)
        MOV r0, #0          @Set READ device to the STDIN (keyboard)
        SWI 0
        POP {R1-R8, lr}
    
    @String fix takes a string value at r1's address and changes the line feed to be null termianted.   
    strfx:
        LDRB r0, [r1],#1    @loads a single byte from r1 (r1 is dereferenced), which is the _sInput to r0
        CMP r0, #10         @is r0 our newline?
        BNE strfx
        
        MOV r0, #0          @set r0 to null
        STRB r0, [r1, #-1]  @store r0's value back into r1's current address location. The final address 
        MOV PC, LR          @location of r1 newline to be the NULL in r1.

    _exit:
    MOV r7, #1
    SWI #0
    
 .data
    
    prompt:     .asciz "\nPlease enter 4 different numbers between 1-5 together without space or special characters. \n \n"
    newline:    .asciz  "\n"
    userInput:  .space 6
```

Answer (score 3):

You're reading four characters. When the user enters `"1234\n"` (five characters), the newline is left in the input buffer to be read by the shell. When the user enters `"123\n"`, the newline is actually read by you. Since you have newline-handling code, the solution is simple: you need to read five characters, not four.